# Access USB Files through Web App

Tags: web-applications, web, usb, raspberry-pi, mp3

I've been playing around with my new Raspberry Pi and want to start making a Wifi controlled music player (Can select a song with my phone, will play from the Raspberry Pi into my speakers).

There's a few options already available such as RuneAudio and RaspyFi. They say they can both read music files from USB drives but how?

Any ideas how I can implement my self?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the USB drive supposed to be connected to the Raspberry Pi?  If so, it is easy for any program running on the Raspberry Pi to access it, the same way you would access any other file.